# Converting audio file into text file using pocketsphinx

Tags: android, record, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

Good day ma'am/sirs! I'm new to android app developing, and I'm really in need of help. I'm developing a Speech-to-Text app though its not the usual STT apps that are available on app-stores. I'm using pocketsphinx for offline speech recognition and conversion, and Android Studio IDE.

My app has three main features and those are:

1. Record - here is where the user will be able to record his/her speech. The recorded speech will be saved into the device's storage.
2. Library - Here is where the user will be able to see his/her recorded speech and converted audio-to-text files. Also the convert feature where the user may convert his/her recorded speech into text files.
3. Edit - here is where the user will be able to edit his/her audio/text files. Only cut, delete, and modify(only text) are the available features.

My main problem is, is it actually possible to convert a **recorded speech** into text by **using pocketsphinx**? To make it more understandable, I've tried demos of pocketsphinx and what I've experienced through it is when you speak through your device, it directly converts what you said. Unlike my idea, where you may record your speech, and convert it into text whenever you want. I'm so confused if its possible, if yes, may someone tell/explain to me how? If no, may someone tell/explain to me the other ways to follow my idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your question is basically: "Does pocketsphinx do STT?"  That sounds like a question for their product team.

Comment: That's not what I meant on my question. What I really mean is, does pocketsphinx do conversion of **recorded** audio into text file? When I tried their demos, yes it converts pretty well, but it converts what it has **recognized**. The point of my question may be seen through the bold words.

Comment: Please excuse me if I may be not good in expressing what I really mean, I'm not good in English language, but I'm trying my best to express my point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give a file as input to Pocketsphinx on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008111/give-a-file-as-input-to-pocketsphinx-on-android)

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev, would you mind if you answer this thread with the same answer you put there, but with an explanation of each class/method you used in there? I have to know how it works so I'd get it easily.

Comment: I know its a lot to ask, but I have to know and learn how it works.