# Having <s> and </s> as an output from android pocketsphinx

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

We're using pocketsphinx to help us convert .wav files into text files. We don't know why it gives us a strange output as it gives us only `<s>` and `</s>` after the conversion. We're using the default dictionary, langauge model and acoustic model given by the cmusphinx community.

Here is the code we're using for the conversion:

```
package com.example.saling_wika.saling_wika;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Config;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Decoder;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Segment;

import static android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.TAG;
import static junit.framework.Assert.fail;





public class ConversionModule extends Activity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
    }
    Config c;
    Decoder ps;
    FileInputStream stream;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        c = Decoder.defaultConfig();

    /*Configuring decoder object*/
        c.setString("-hmm", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.example.saling_wika.saling_wika/files/sync", "en-us-ptm").getPath());
        c.setString("-dict", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.example.saling_wika.saling_wika/files/sync", "cmudict-en-us.dict").getPath());
        c.setString("-lm", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.example.saling_wika.saling_wika/files/sync", "weather.dmp").getPath());
        c.setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true);


        ps = new Decoder(c);


        try {
            final File file = new File(AudioToConvert.pathko);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            File auxFile = new File(uri.getPath());
            stream = new FileInputStream(auxFile);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        ps.startUtt();
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        try {
            int nbytes;
            while ((nbytes = stream.read(b)) >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b, 0, nbytes);
                short[] s = new short[nbytes / 2];
                bb.asShortBuffer().get(s);
                ps.processRaw(s, nbytes / 2, false, false);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        ps.endUtt();
        //  System.out.println(ps.hyp().getHypstr());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ps.hyp().getHypstr(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (Segment seg : ps.seg()) {
            //  System.out.println(seg.getWord());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),seg.getWord(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        ;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained on [CMUSphinx forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/d256cd01/) you have multiple issues:

1. You need to add `bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` as described in [Give a file as input to Pocketsphinx on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008111/give-a-file-as-input-to-pocketsphinx-on-android)
2. Your input file should have PCM format 16khz 16 bit mono. In case you want to submit some encoded file you need to decode it to raw data first.

Comment: Hi I used the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37640851/1693203, and I am having the same problem. I have an 11 second wav file with a native English speaker saying a short sentence. The file is 16 bit, little endian, 16 kHz and I have removed the wav header, so the file only has the raw audio part. I am getting result <s> [speech] <sil> [speech] <sil> [speech] </s>. Can you give me a few hints on how to solve this, please?

Comment: By the way I get the same result if I use the file keeping the wav header